# How can I modify veins source code to build my first VANET simulation trigger by a RSU?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In a section of road (I exported a portion of map from osm), I have already placed a RSU and generate some random trips of some vehicles. I would like now simulate the exchanges of messages as described bellow:
- the RSU broadcasts periodically a message, like WSA or SAM (Service Announcement Message), and all vehicles that receive the message will respond to the RSU.
Hence, I would like to simulate packet loss according to the number of vehicles and number of exchanges messages handled by the RSU.
I don't know where to change the first sender of message in the original veins source code. In the original veins program, it is a node[0] that triggers the accident message.

Thank you in advance for your return.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code of the application running in the Veins 5a1 example simulation in [`src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc)

I would recommend to start learning about Veins by running the example simulation and playing around with the above mentioned file to see how/what the behavior of the simulation changes.

If you are new to OMNeT++ as well, you will likely find it very useful to start by learning plain OMNeT++ (that is, without Veins) first. The [OMNeT++ Tic Toc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) is an excellent place to start here.